# How to add starting animation delay to lottie-react-native

Tags: react-native, lottie

This is my component and I want the animation to start 0.5s after the page has been landed on. How can I achieve this?

**No props for delay here:**
https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native/

```
<Lottie
  style={[
    {
      position: 'relative',
      height: 160,
      width: 160,
    },
    spacing.gbMt1,
  ]}
  autoPlay={true}
  loop={false}
  source={require('../assets/lottie/Coach001.json')}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no prop for adding time delay but you can use [these](https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods-imperative-api) API methods to play, pause, resume and reset animation. You will need to set autoplay to false and call "play" method in timeout of 5 seconds to achieve the required delay.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    ref?.current?.play();
  }, 500)
}, [])
```

```
<Lottie
  ref={ref}
  style={[
    {
      position: 'relative',
      height: 160,
      width: 160,
    },
    spacing.gbMt1,
  ]}
  autoPlay={false}
  loop={false}
  source={require('../assets/lottie/Coach001.json')}
/>
```